# How do I pass command line arguments to docker-compose run?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to pass arguments to the underlying command that docker-compose runs, but I'm not sure how to do it.

This is what my non-docker command looked like:

```
npm run test:watch -- --verbose --match="matching test name"
```

Which passes `--verbose --match="matching test name"` to the test runner.

Now I want to run my tests in docker but I can't get this to work:

```
docker-compose run test-service-name -- --verbose --match="matching test name"
```

Is this possible or how should I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`docker-compose run` will interpret `-- --verbose --match="matching test name"` as the command and arguments

```
Usage:
    run [options] [-v VOLUME...] [-p PORT...] [-e KEY=VAL...] [-l KEY=VALUE...]
        SERVICE [COMMAND] [ARGS...]
```

You should put the command and all the arguments in the cli

```
docker-compose run test-service-name npm run test:watch --verbose --match="matching test name"
```

docker-compose is used to simplify not to complicate things up, for this you can define it permanently in the `docker-compose.yml` file using command

```
command: npm run test:watch --verbose --match="matching test name"
```

source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command